# Probability distribution of actual value based on observed value with error relative to the actual value?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, measurement-error

I use a method of estimation (a variant of [HyperLogLog](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/FlFuGaMe07.pdf)) that estimates cardinality of some set with a "relative error". Let's assume $$\hat{\rho} \sim \mathcal{N}(\rho,(\rho c)^2) $$ where $\rho$ is the actual value and $\hat{\rho}$ is the observed value.

What I'm interested in is the probability that the actual value for an observed value be larger than a certain number:
$$ P(\rho>\rho_m|\hat{\rho})$$

Now if the error was not "relative" (e.g. standard deviation of the normal distribution above was constant) this would have been trivial, but I still believe this should be well known given that "relative errors" are not all that uncommon. What am I missing?